# Potential reasons for screening in Panama

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, panama

I am an Indian citizen with a US student visa (which was valid for over two years from the time of the incident). I was solo traveling in South America (Colombia and Peru) for a few weeks, and I had no issues entering either country with my US visa. On the way back to the US, I booked my tickets so that I would have three days in Panama. I imagined there would be no issue as Panama also allows Indian citizens to travel without a Panama visa as long as they have a US visa. However, just before boarding my flight from Lima to Panama City, I was asked a lot of questions (including some strange ones such as when my passport had been last stamped by any country). After about 20 minutes, I was allowed to board the flight.

Upon disembarking, I found out that there were Panama customs officials waiting for me at the gate. I was asked to follow them and I was asked to answer many questions, some of which they clearly knew the answer to. For instance, when I was first questioned at the gate, they told me, without asking me, that I was intending to stay in Panama for three days. But at the customs office, I was asked the same question thrice.

Then, all the entry and exit stamps in my passport stamp were carefully examined by a team of four custom officials. After almost 45 minutes of questioning, I was allowed in.

I asked them what all of this had been about, and they said it is "standard" for Indian citizens entering Panama for the first time with a US visa. That does not sound right at all.

Has something similar happened to anyone before? I have a few theories:

1. As a single male having traveled to countries somewhat infamously known for drugs and then entering Panama without a Panama visa, I might have triggered some warnings.
2. I was denied a Canadian visa without any explicit reason to present at a prestigious conference even though I am a PhD student from a well-known university. Something from my travel history or background raises red flags? Although what, I have no idea and of course none of you can answer it for me. But maybe someone had similar issues?
3. Unlikely, but the not-so-great relationship between Colombia and Panama might be a problem? I only thought of this because of the careful examination of entry and exit stamps by Copa Airlines officials in Lima and by the customs officers in Panama.

I know any answer is at best a guess, but some thoughts or similar previous experiences will be helpful. If there is something stupid I am doing, I'd at least like to try and fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is anything we can answer, but my first guess is that you share a name with somebody on a watch list.  Do you have a Muslim name by any chance?

Comment: Nope. It is an uncommon name, however.

Comment: Panama has a fairly strong [data protection law](https://icazalaw.com/personal-data-protection-law-and-its-regulations-in-panama/) which, in theory, should give you the right to request any information the Migration Department holds on you and to see if it is relevant to your questions. However, I was not able to find any information about the process for actually doing so on [their website](https://www.migracion.gob.pa/), so you may need to do more research and/or consult with local lawyers in order to proceed.

Comment: Was there at any point any search or examination of your belongings? If not, the drug angle can probably be forgotten, in favour of either an immigration issue or a security issue. Asking questions they know the answer to or asking the same question multiple times is a classic method to attempt to detect inconsistencies or lies. But it’s indeed difficult to guess what triggered it, especially as they started before boarding. Is your passport damaged in any way?